# How to grep text between two commas

Tags: grep

i have a string in text file, i want to grep the email address but it is not working

```
26,2,12,1,1,0,1,0,12,20,648130864.573339,,"iCloud - Device Locator",,,69FFBE2F-6626-4A4B-8A78-BF7D06DE59C7,7F223B27-9588-4719-81B9-074666A76E1D,com.apple.accountsd,youremail@yahoo.com,
```

i try: `grep -Eo "\b@'[^']*'"` but it not working

i need output: youremail@yahoo.com

P/s: maybe the field isn't 19th but email is always at the end of the line

Comment: You've said nothing about the properties of this text string or whether that's the only thing in the file.  For example, is the string a properly quoted CSV record, always? If not, might there be embedded commas in some field so that the email is not strictly in the 19th field? If so, will the email address always be in the second to last field?

Comment: email is always at the end of the line

Comment: but in your example there is another comma in the end... that means it would be the second to last field.

Comment: `grep -o '[^,]*@[^,]*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the email is always the 19th item, you can use

```
cut -d, -f 19
```

`-d,` means ',' is the delimiter and `-f 19` means you want the 19th field.

###### Update:

If the email is always the *penultimate* item on the line (note that you have a comma after it), you can use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/.*,\(.*\),/\1/'
```

Comment: it working but Email is random, can there be 1 command for all cases?

Comment: what do you mean "is random" ?

Comment: maybe the field isn't 19th (random) but email is always at the end of the line

Comment: `sed -e 's/.*,\(.*\),/\1/'`

Comment: Thank You very much, it's working: sed -e 's/.*,\(.*\),/\1/'

Answer (score 3):

Use `csvcut` from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
csvcut -c 19 file
```

---

Alternatively, you might try want to try `awk` if it is always the second to last field:

```
awk -F, '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

This won't work if the last field contained a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comma on the line with a sed. Then remove everything before and including the last comma, this leaves the email address, as follows:

```
XXXX@Atlas:~$ echo "26,2,12,1,1,0,1,0,12,20,648130864.573339,,"iCloud - Device Locator",,,69FFBE2F-6626-4A4B-8A78-BF7D06DE59C7,7F223B27-9588-4719-81B9-074666A76E1D,com.apple.accountsd,youremail@yahoo.com," | sed "s/,$//g; s/^.*,//g"
youremail@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
raku -ne 'for .split(",") {.put if m:g/ \@ /;};'
```

OUTPUT:

```
youremail@yahoo.com
```

The `:g` 'global' adverb allows for more that one match. If you're absolutely certain of the desired field, you could drop the `m/.../` match and add an index (e.g. `[18]`):

```
raku -ne '.put for .split(",")[18];'
```

OUTPUT:

```
youremail@yahoo.com
```

https://raku.org/

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` by reversing the input, so that the email becomes the second comma delimited field, and finally reverse once more:

```
< file rev | cut -d, -f2 | rev 
youremail@yahoo.com
```

Using comma as field separator:

```
perl -F, -pale '$_ = pop @F' < file
```

turn commas to newlines then keep chopping until we're left with one newline

```
sed -n 'y/,/\n/;/\n.*\n/D;P' < file
```